# Problems with Option of select angular 6

Tags: angular6, html-select

I don't know when I to use value or ngvalue the option don't work

```
   <select class="browser-default" [(ngModel)]="candidate.party" name="party">
        <option *ngFor="let iten of parties" [selected]="iten?.key === candidate.party_id ? true : false" [ngValue]="1">{{ iten?.name }}</option>
    </select>
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

too set the selected option of an select you have too use **[(ngModel)]**. In Component you need two variables. parties is your array used for options and selectedParty is used for ngModel.

e.g. onInit

```
this.selectedParty = this.parties[0];
```

would set selected option too first item of parties.